# How can I write things like "Does this dictionary use a different database from Jisho.org's?"

Tags: translation

Sorry if that question is too specific. I don't know if I'm allowed to ask it.

I don't know how to say that part: use a different database from Jisho.org's?

I tried to write like this:

> その辞書がjisho.orgのと別データベースを使いますか。

Is there something wrong?

Comment: There are two grammatical errors and one unnatural expression in your attempt, but *unfocused* translation checks are off-topic here. Could you at least explain which part of your translation is most difficult to you?

Comment: I think the asker has done enough research effort on his own. @Tito, how about「その辞書はjisho.orgとは別のデータベースを使いますか。」

Comment: I tried to use "jisho.orgの" to mean like "Jisho.org's one". I have difficulties in that part I mentioned on the post because of that doubt. According to DXV, the rest is almost fine. Am I allowed to ask questions like that?

Comment: Regarding that construction by DXV: Jisho.orgとは別のデータベース. Doesn't that mean "a database different from Jisho.org" as if Jisho.org was a database instead of a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use は instead of が. It may seem to be a simple mistake, but it makes the sentence look very unnatural.
- Use 使っていますか instead of 使いますか for the same reason [why you have to say 知っている, 結婚している](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36928/5010), etc.
- It's better to say "jisho.org(の)と別**の**データベース" than "jisho.orgのと別データベース". (The first の after jisho.org is optional; for example 彼と別の犬を飼う does not mean the speaker is thinking 彼 is a dog.)

Corrected sentence:

> その辞書**は**jisho.orgと別**の**データベースを使**ってい**ますか。

<sub>PS: General translation checks are basically off-topic. Next time please try to make a question and title that focuses on one specific grammar point, word usage, etc. (Because that is the rule; we can review other parts of your translation, anyway.)</sub>